# verifyNoMoreInteractions fails when iterating a collection of mocks

Tags: java, mockito

I have this code snippet that I want to unit test:

```
public void method(Set<Foo> fooList){
    for (Foo f : fooList) {
       EnumClass i = f.get();
    }
}
```

And I have this test code in Mockito:

```
Collection<Foo> mockFoos = Sets.newHashSet(mockFoo1, mockFoo2);
when(mockFoo1.get()).thenReturn(*some enum value*);
when(mockFoo2.get()).thenReturn(*some enum value*);
...
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockFoos.toArray())
```

And for some reason the test fails, I also tried added logging and the mocks and the only recorded interactions are calls to `get`.

I dont think it matters but Foo extends from some other class.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by using `ignoreStubs`, mockito seem to consider the "invocation" of `get` in `when(mockFoo1.get()).thenReturn(*some enum value*);` as an unstubbed invocation and thats why it failed, the solution was to use:
`verifyNoMoreInteractions(ignoreStubs(mockFoos.toArray()))`

Answer (score 0):

mockFoos.toArray() will create new object and mockito will work with it not your mockFoos collection.

According to the mockito documentation the last line should be
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockFoos)

Comment: Didnt work, also tried to add `verifyNoMoreInteractions` on the individual mocks that are inside the collection, still didnt work

Comment: Do you gen error, or the test just doesn't pass by saying there were more interactions

Comment: Same error, test fails before I has unexpected interactions

Comment: can you provide the whole java file?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I added logs to the mock and it seems to be failing because its counting the call I make when I create a `when` expectation in mockito as a call that wasnt stubbed and thats why it fails.